# Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Undefined method `external email='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, gitlab

My Gitlab Environment:

1. GitLab 9.5.2
2. GitLab Shell 5.8.0
3. GitLab Workhorse v3.0.0
4. GitLab API v4
5. Git 2.13.5
6. Ruby 2.3.3p222
7. Rails 4.2.8
8. postgresql 9.6.3

My Gitlab LDAP configuration:

```
 gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
##! **remember to close this block with 'EOS' below**
 gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = YAML.load <<-'EOS'
   main: # 'main' is the GitLab 'provider ID' of this LDAP server
     label: 'LDAP'
     host: '192.168.21.7'
     port: 389
     uid: 'mail'
     bind_dn: 'cn=MyUserName,ou=MIS,ou=SZ,dc=r-pac,dc=local'
     password: 'MyPassword'
     encryption: 'plain' # "start_tls" or "simple_tls" or "plain"
     verify_certificates: false
     ca_file: ''
     ssl_version: ''
     active_directory: true
     allow_username_or_email_login: false
     block_auto_created_users: false
     base: 'ou=MIS,ou=SZ,dc=r-pac,dc=local'
     user_filter: ''
     attributes:
       username: ['uid', 'userid', 'sAMAccountName']
       email:    ['mail']
       name:       'cn'
       first_name: 'givenName'
       last_name:  'sn'
     ## EE only
     group_base: ''
     admin_group: ''
     sync_ssh_keys: false
 EOS
```

I can't login today. It's always been possible.Throw exception when login:

> Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Undefined method
>   `external email=' for #<user id:2 @allen.cai> did you mean?
>   external=".

I execute command check **gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check**

```
Checking LDAP ...

Server: ldapmain
LDAP authentication... Success
LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (only showing the first 100 results)
......
```

**Can someone help me? Thanks :)**

Comment: is strange: it should be xxx@allen.ca, no?

Comment: This tip is really strange, but it's been normal before today. @VonC

Comment: Is there an extra space somewhere? Do you mean the same account wwas working fine with LDAP and GitLab before today?

Comment: I mean yesterday using LDAP to successfully login Gitlab, login failed today.
@VonC

Comment: Did you recently upgraded GitLab (as in https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-login-after-upgrade-to-9-0/7066)

Comment: Yes, you're great! I run `Gitlab` in `Docker` mode, Upgraded from `9.5.2` to `10.0.3`, and found that the new version had too many fatal errors, so I demoted to `9.5.2` @VonC

Comment: I saw this, but it didn't work.`gitlab-rake db:migrate` and `gitlab-ctl restart` @VonC

Comment: I upgrade to `10.1.0` and found that the problem of `LDAP` authentication login was solved @VonC

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is that I upgraded `Gitlab` from `9.5.2` version to `10.0.3`.
Thank [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) provides links to solutions to similar problems:
https://forum.gitlab.com/t/cannot-login-after-upgrade-to-9-0/7066
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/29957
I execute `gitlab-rake db:migrate` and `gitlab-ctl restart` command, **but didn't work**, `LDAP` Authentication login still has a problem.

**Finally, i try to upgrade to the `10.1.0` and found that the problem of `LDAP` authentication login was solved. :)**

> Have this kind of problem friend, if you also plan to use the upgrade
>   way to solve the `LDAP` authentication login problem, **please backup your
>   `Gitlab` data**, once upgrade cannot solve the problem, use your backup
>   data to restore and rolled back your `Gitlab`, avoid some unexpected
>   failure, **My `Gitlab` is such a tragic case**.